# FusionAuth and auth_openidc_module jwt.payload handling

Tags: mod-auth-openidc, fusionauth

I intend to use an Apache httpd server and integrate FusionAuth as OpenId provider.
I added `auth_openidc_module` (https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/) Apache module to handle the `OAUTH2` protocol.

The authorization end with the following error message:

> oidc_proto_validate_nonce: id_token JSON payload did not contain a
>   "nonce" string

The payload looks like (sub key and app id anonymized):

```
jwt.payload="{"aud":"21722795-f49c-4c66-83b8-36119551c788",
"exp":1553022856,
"iat":1553022556,
"iss":"issuer",
"sub":"<key>",
"authenticationType":"PASSWORD",
"email_verified":true,
"applicationId":"<app key>",
"roles":["Member"]}"
```

The "nonce" value seems to be transferred separately and not recognized by `auth_openidc_module`.

How do I configure either `FusionAuth` or `auth_openidc_module` to establish a successful authorization?

Answer (score 1):

FusionAuth does not currently support the `nonce` parameter in the `id_token`.

This will be supported in the upcoming 1.5.0 release. I'll add a comment to this thread when it is available, currently targeting the end of this week.

**Update** : Available since version 1.5.0.

Comment: may I suggest that FusionAuth uses openid.net/certification to verify its compliancy to the spec

Comment: @HansZ. we are working on OpenID compliance and hopefully it will be ready in the near future. Stay tuned!

Comment: Thanks for the answer,. I am looking   forward to the 1.5 Release.

Comment: @Andreas, version 1.5.0 is available.